# How can I Create a webservice with three or more fields to authentication

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, security, authentication

Can I create a webservice (.Net & C#) with secure authentication using doesn't only pair login and password but more a new field? Example kind of HASH?

Comment: Yes; that is completely possible.

Comment: Hey @SLaks, I'm newbie in .Net World and I'm doing something. Do you have some examples for to do this?

Comment: Make sure you ignore ASMX web services. You want to be using WCF services.

Comment: Look into ASP.Net Web API.